# How to get an InputStream of a Java class properly? Gitlab CI fails

Tags: java, inputstream, gitlab-ci

I experienced a problem today, I want to get an InputStream of a java base class and my code works properly on my personal computer but when I push the code on Gitlab, Gitlab CI fails because it does not find the java class.

```
try (InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/java/lang/String.class")) {
    System.out.println(inputStream); //Displays null on gitlab CI only
}
```

I think my way to get the InputStream is the cause of this bug.

EDIT : I want to be able to get an InputStream of ArrayList.class or String.class or Object.class... More or less all classes contained in JDK.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: There really isn't such a thing as 'an input stream of a java base class', so it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish - you should describe that in your question.

Comment: Does this work? `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`

Comment: @jrtapsell It doesn't works on gitlab CI, just on my computer

Comment: There isn't a guaranteed portable way to do this in Java but you are probably best off calling getResrouce on the class you are interested in, rather than some random class. so `String.class.get...` etc.

Comment: I think your problem is the security manager of the server JVM. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Comment: Is there a way to lower the security level on gitlab (in .gitlab-ci.yml or other) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a security problem with the maven image used in my  .gitlab-ci.yml. I used **3.5.0-ibmjava-9** image because **3.5.0-jdk-9** as an issue with SSL certificates. 
To solve my problem, I switched to **3.5.0-jdk-9-slim** which has no SSL issue and I think a lower security check with internal classes.

Thanks for all and for comments about security. They help me a lot :D